# Magento 1 can't connect to database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error

Please Helpme on this,I have copied a live site to a development environment so I can do some testing. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_move.htm) to get everything up and running.

When I go to the site is says that there has been an error. The log says the following: `"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`

I have multiple other magento instances running on the same machine and they all work. The database is on a different machine.

My local.xml is all correct and when I create a simple php test page which contains the following:

```
<?php
      $mysqli=mysqli_connect("[same data as local.xml]");
      if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
          printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
          exit();
      }else{
          echo "Connection succesfull!";
      }
?>
```

The page is returning: Connection succesfull!

I've tried: restarting apache2 and php5-fpm, clearing cache and session folder, removing the other `.xml` files in `/app/etc except local.xml` and config.xml.

Can somebody help me fix this problem?
Thanks in advance!

[see link](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_move.htm)

Comment: Check in  app/etc/local.xml  database credential is correct or not?

Comment: have you cleaned the var/cache folder?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for the correctness of your entry made in app/etc/local.xml
2. Check in the table "core_config_data" for if there is a correct entry for the row of secure and insecure base-URL
3. Try to replace the .htaccess file present at the root with the .htaccess file which comes with the bare Magento version of your Magento site